# is $\int_e^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x} \sin x dx$ converges absolutely?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Is $\int_e^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x} \sin x dx$ converges absolutely?

Is the following right?

$$\int_e^\infty \left| \frac{\ln x}{x} \sin x \right| dx \le \int_e^\infty \left| \frac{\ln x}{x} \right| dx \le \int_e^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x} dx$$

Using integration by parts:

$$= \ln^2 x |_e^\infty  - \int_e^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x}$$

Hence,

$$2\int_e^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x} = \ln^2(\infty) - \ln^2(e) = \infty$$

Therefore, the integral doesn't converge absolutely.

I wish to know whether my proof is valid or not.

Thanks

Comment: Note that you have only shown that your quantity is $\leq+\infty$ (and we already knew that..), so you cannot conclude that it diverges..

Comment: Oh right (5 more to go...)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the fact that $\displaystyle \int_e^{+\infty}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$ is not converging is not enough to prove that your integral does not converge absolutely since your are not considering the initial integral anymore but something that might be bigger.

Here is an idea: for every $x\geq e$, $\ln(x)\geq 1$ hence $$\left|\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}\sin(x)\right|\geq \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}.$$
But $$\int_e^{+\infty} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx$$ doesn't converge.

Indeed if $n\geq 3$ :
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{e}^{n\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx  & = \int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \int_{2\pi}^{n\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx \\
& =\int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} (-1)^k\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}dx \\
& \geq \int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi} (-1)^k\dfrac{\sin(x+k\pi)}{x+k\pi}dx \\
& = \int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+k\pi}dx \\
& \geq \int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{k\pi}dx \\
& = \int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\dfrac{2}{k\pi} \\
& = \int_{e}^{2\pi} \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx + \dfrac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k} \\
\end{align*}$$
when $n$ goes to $+\infty$, the right hand side goes to $+\infty$

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't it be though $(-1)^{k+1}$?

Comment: No since $\sin(x)$ is positive on $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ iff $k$ is even.